# Защита памяти и передача управления в стек

Tags: c, память, безопасность

Читаю книгу "Искусство эксплойта" и в какой то момент демонстрируется уязвимость переполнения буфера. В стек программы внедряется шелл-код, на который после передается управление. Попытался повторить, однако получил ошибку сегментации. Так ли работает защита памяти? Вот пример:

```
void some_func()
{
    char buffer[20];
    int i;  

    strcpy(buffer, "\x90\x90\x90\x90");// - Обычные NOP инструкции процессора

    for(i = 5; i != 10; ++i)
    {
        *((unsigned*)buffer + i) = buffer;// - Адрес возврата функции перезаписывается на адрес массива
    }
}
```

В отладчике, в регистре инструкций процессора уже записался адрес buffer. Однако выполнение следующей инструкции выдало ошибку сегментации памяти.

Comment: экспойты это весело. чуть не туда байт записал и все. один битик не такой и все в разнос. может там нужны особые опции компиляции или фаза луны.

Comment: Во-первых это программа содержит неопределенное поведение, соответственно никаких оснований писать *"Адрес возврата функции перезаписывается на адрес массива"* нет. Во-вторых для выполнения кода блок памяти должен иметь соответствующий флаг.

Comment: Вы перезаписываете несколько подряд идущих слов на стеке, почему? Здесь не только адрес возврата перезаписывается, а ещё и другие области. А по поводу соответствующего флага - запишите в стек вместо адреса массива адрес какой-нибудь функции. В ней у вас будет понятный код, а не код инструкции NOP, который ещё не факт, что равен 0х90.

Comment: Вопрос состоит больше в том, разрешают ли современные системы, посредством защиты памяти, такие вот передачи управления в стек с дальнейшим выполнением инструкций в нем. Я читал, что доступ на исполнение имеет только cегмент кода, ну и дополнительно выделенные области памяти, помеченные нужным флагом. Хотелось убедиться, что именно эта причина вызвала ошибку сегментации памяти.  Перезаписав адрес возврата, просто на другой адрес из сегмента кода, выполнение продолжилось как и предполагалось. Однако как и писал, инструкции по адресу buffer выполняться не захотели

Comment: Да, то, что инструкции по адресу buffer выполняться не захотели - это как раз потому, что стек не имеет разрешения на исполнение. И именно это вызвало ошибку сегментирования.